# How to compress video file before uploading to the server in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload video file (Captured/Selected from gallery) to the Server but currently it takes lot of time so, I want to compress the video file before uploading it to the server. I searched a lot but yet didn't find any acceptable solution. Please help. Thank you..

Comment: video files are not compressable. What you can do is to convert the video to other format by losing quality.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "FFMPEG" library. You can find details at https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper.

I found it not difficult to start with.